# launchimage can not display

Tags: xcode, launchimage

[image]

I drag the .png into the launchimage,but the images all have gray edge.you can see it in my uploaded pictures.If it is right,it should have no gray edge.I am sure the size of my images have no problem.I do not know the where is the problem,thank you!

Comment: I know the size iPhone Portrait iOS 8-Retina HD 5.5 （1242×2208）
iPhone Portrait iOS 8-Retina HD 4.7 （750×1334）
iPhone Portrait iOS 7,8-2x （640×960）
iPhone Portrait iOS 7,8-Retina 4 （640×1136）

Comment: Have you added an imageView with auto layout? This probably happens because the image is out of bounds of the view.

Comment: I have learned it.Because my launch image is white,so apple make it have a gray edge automaticly.It is not an error.It is right . Thank you !